# Django url variable not passing

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get a variable from url and display it in template using django.
Here's the page with the link to the bucket's page:

```
<div id="left">
   <a href="{% url 'project:bucket' bucket=bucket.bucketName %}"><h4 id='s3ItemName'>{{ bucket.bucketName }}</h4></a>
</div>
```

This displays the bucket name properly and contains a link to abucket detail page. My urls.py look like this:

```
url(r'bienbox/bucket/(?P<bucket>\w+)$',views.bucketPage.as_view(),name='bucket')
```

Now, here's views.py

```
class bucketPage(TemplateView):
template_name = "project/bucket.html"

def get(self, request, bucket):
    bucketName = request.GET.get('bucket')
    return render(request,self.template_name,{'bucketName': bucketName})
```

So I'm passing the `bucketName` variable here, however when the page opens I get "None" instead of the variable name. Here's the bucket.html:

```
<div class="mainPage">
   <div class="s3Wrapper">
      <h2>{{ bucketName }}</h2>
   </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is the variable not passed?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self.request.GET` holds variables from the querystring, e.g. if you did `/bienbox/bucket/?bucket=mybucket`.

In your case, you can get the bucket name from `self.kwargs`.

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    bucketName = self.kwargs['bucket']
    return render(request,self.template_name,{'bucketName': bucketName})
```

Try to avoid overriding `get` or `post` when you use class based views. In this case you could do:

```
class bucketPage(TemplateView):
    template_name = "project/bucket.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(bucketPage, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['bucketName'] = self.kwargs['bucket']
        return context
```

Comment: In the `get` method `kwargs['bucket']` is enough. I’m used to doing `self.kwargs['bucket']`, which works in other methods like `get_context_data`.